# Discovered my bathroom exhaust fan has no ventilation, what do I do?

Tags: bathroom, attic, venting

Asking for help or advice on how I should run the new ducting for the existing bathroom exhaust fan. Whether I should run the ducting to the soffit, siding or roof? I would also ask for "Pros" and "Cons" to previous listed choices whether it be by skill level or finance, (i.e what are the pros and cons to routing the ducting through the roof?). Also, this bathroom exhaust fan was originally installed in the early 80's, so I believe judging by the, rapid-moose-making-love-to-an-elderly-non-consenting-bear, type sound coming from the motor that it's about time to install a new one.

Comment: **rapid-moose-making-love-to-an-elderly-non-consenting-bear, type sound** OMG you are so funny

Comment: What’s above the vent? Attic? Another habitable floor?

Comment: Usually duct direction/placement should use the shortest and easiest and straightest way.  You want to limit bends and distance.

Comment: Sometimes you can route the duct to the soffit and have it use a soffit vent (either existing or installed for this purpose).

Answer (score 1):

Going through the siding would probably be the easiest but I doubt you'll have much siding at that point unless it's a two story unit. If running the duct in an attic, heading toward a soffit works well but you need to terminate the duct with a vent attached to the soffit. Don't just leave the duct laying up close to the soffit because most of the the vented air will stay in the attic. Going through the roof will probably yield the shortest path and least amount of elbows but then you're stuck working up on a roof and you then have to seal the duct to prevent roof leaks. That in it's self usually scares people away from the roof vent.

This would also be the perfect time to replace the vent.

Comment: Good answer, but just to mention that in my jurisdictions, you can’t exit within 3’ of any opening (windows, soffit vents, intakes). Check your local regs.

Answer (score 1):

So you're buying a new fan, a roll of insulated 4 inch duct and an appropriate exit vent.   My two cents on where to exit:

- If your room's ceiling joists run towards an exterior wall, it is by far the easiest thing to install a ceiling fan and run the duct between the joists to that wall.
- If the room's exterior wall runs parallel to the ceiling joists then if you have bizarrely oversized joists you may be able to drill 4 inch holes through them, otherwise that wall is not an option.  If you can run along the joists through an adjacent room towards a different outside wall, you might choose to do that but will probably need to cut open the ceiling in the adjacent room.
- In the above situation (wall parallel to joists) if the room is on the upper floor, beneath the roof and there is an adjacent soffit you can install a ceiling fan in the outermost joist bay, run horizontally a few feet to minimize noise, then up through the ceiling into the attic crawl space, then between the rafters into the soffit.  Install a soffit vent there on the end of the duct.  There are a lot of bends in this plan so minimize them.
- If you have an unfinished attic with appropriate access, once you go through the ceiling into the attic, you can run the duct anywhere, for example a gable wall.
- I'm not a fan of going through the roof but some people with more experience swear by it.  If you are on an upper floor you just go straight up, and install an appropriate roof vent.
- In really strange situations where all the above have problems you can buy a "through the wall" fan.  I don't like those but they serve a purpose.  In countries where the temperatures don't get too extreme they often install ones with no duct and no baffles.  Literally a hole in the wall with a screen and a fan.

Answer (score 0):

When I ran into the same scenario in the house I live in now, I did two things

1. Buy a newer fan with better CFMs. The cheapo builder-basic fan is typically 4 sones (loud) and moves 50CFM. These last a surprisingly long time but... well... I liked your description of the noise. My replacement fan is 0.8 sones and 90CFM (keep it under 100CFM, or you'll need to go to 6" ducting, which is slightly harder to work with and somewhat more expensive).
2. Find the nearest exit point to the fan. In my case, that was the roof about 3 feet above the fan.

Exits can be through the wall, roof, or soffit (there's a different vent for each). I would **highly** recommend using insulated duct line (limits how much condensation occurs).

- The soffit vent is easiest, but it can allow warm, moist air to re-enter your attic.
- The wall vent works just like a dryer exhaust on a vertical exterior wall. Same soffit problem as soffit vents (warm air rises)
- Roof vent kits are the gold standard (vents out the top) and are easy to find

The roof vent does sound scary, but if you're dealing with 4" ducting, it shouldn't be hard. I would highly recommend a 4 1/8" hole drill for this. You'll cut from the top down, then use a utility knife to cut the remaining shingles away to fit the vent hood. The top part of the vent hood will slide up under the shingles above it. Caulk the top and two sides (not the bottom to allow water to flow out) underneath the vent hood with a good exterior or roofing caulk. Once it's in place over the hole, nail it down with roofing nails, and then dab some of your caulk over the nails to prevent leaking. The Broan kits (fairly ubiquitous) can be zip-tied to the duct flange and then the flange screws into the exhaust hood on the roof.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a situation in a house with 3 bathrooms where none of the exhaust fans had airflow. Everything was installed properly except that the damper flaps still had the shipping tape holding them closed. This allowed a very small amount of air to flow and the fan blades were loaded with dust. Removing the tape and cleaning the fans solved the rattling noise and got the air flowing. I have also seen where a few drops of oil in the right places on the motor bearings has stopped weird noises and slow starting fans.